# running time of algorithm does not match the reality

Tags: big-o

I have the following algorithm:

[image]

I analyzed this algoritm as follow:

Since the outer for loop goes from i to n it iterates at most n times,
and the loop on j iterates again from i to n which we can say at most n times,
if we do the same with the whole algorithm we have 4 nested for loop so the running time would be O(n^4).

But when I run this code for different input size I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see the result is much closer to n^3? can anyone explain why does this happen or what is wrong with my analysis that I get a loose bound?

Comment: It's `O(n^4)` you just need to look at big enough n. The lower order terms are relatively bigger for small `n` so they dominate. The `O(n^4)` will come through eventually.

Comment: I don't think looking at a counter value is enough to judge how much time this algorithm took.

Comment: i am really not able to understand why are you using count as a factor to calculate running time. Its just a variable its value will depend on the for loop. and clearly here twisting values in for loop will increase the counter value. Morever O(n^4) means worst case scenario which you havent exploited yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, you may proceed like the following, using Sigma Notation, to obtain the order of growth complexity of your algorithm:

[image]

Moreover, the equation obtained tells the exact number of iterations executed inside the innermost loop:

```
int sum = 0;
for( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
    for( j=i ; j<n ; j++ )
        for( k=0 ; k<j ; k++ )
            for( h=0 ; h<i ; h++ )
                sum ++; 
printf("\nsum = %d", sum);
```

When `T(10) = 1155`, `sum = 1155` also.

Comment: h varies from k to i, not from 0 to i, so the result will be a lot smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a conceptual way to see why, but you can prove by induction the above has `(n + 2) * (n + 1) * n * (n - 1) / 24` loops.  Proof left to the reader.

In other words, it is indeed `O(n^4)`.

**Edit:** You're count increases too frequently.  Simply try this code to count number of loops:

```
    for (int n = 0; n < 30; n++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                for(int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                    for (int h = k; h < i; h++) {
                        sum++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(n + ": " + sum + " = " + (n + 2) * (n + 1) * n * (n - 1) / 24);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ,So what if I want to say the running time in theta? If I did not use that code for observation I would say it is asymptotically theta(n^4) but now I am in doubt. Can we say it is theta(n^4)?

Comment: Yes.  I gave you the formula.  It's Theta((n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)/24).

Comment: Great thanks, I observed your formula but as you can see from the result above I get 19 as running time for input size 3 but this formula gives 5. Where  is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are having a rather complex algorithm. The number of operations is clearly less than n^4, but it isn't at all obvious how much less than n^4, and whether it is O (n^3) or not.

Checking the values n = 1 to 9 and making a guess based on the results is rather pointless.

To get a slightly better idea, assume that the number of steps is either c * n^3 or d * n^4, and make a table of the values c and d for 1 <= n <= 1,000. That might give you a better idea. It's not a foolproof method; there are algorithms changing their behaviour dramatically much later than at n = 1,000.

Best method is of course a proof. Just remember that O (n^4) doesn't mean "approximately n^4 operations", it means "at most c * n^4 operations, for some c". Sometimes c is small.